# Selenium IDE: [error] Timed out after 30000ms

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

I'm currently testing a website and my first command (i.e. `open`) is always thrown with `[error] Timed out after 30000ms`.

I added `waitforPageToLoad` with `target=100000` but the same error is consistently thrown which results to `Test case failed`.

Which command should I appropriately use to prevent this error? And can I specify somewhere in the tool that minimum page load toad time for any of my test case is `60000ms`?

Please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page isn't giving a dom ready status within those 30 seconds. You can try using the setTimeout command to increase the timeout for that test.

> setTimeout(timeout)
>       Arguments:
>
> ```
>     timeout - a timeout in milliseconds, after which the action will return with an error
>
> Specifies the amount of time that Selenium will wait for actions to complete.
>
> Actions that require waiting include "open" and the "waitFor*" actions.
> The default timeout is 30 seconds.
> ```

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to select my answer as the right answer then.

Comment: I have <15 reputations, so I I can't vote yet. A big THANK YOU will do for now....Additionally, I observed 'setTimeout' command works when it's placed before 'open'.

Comment: "The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"." so you should be able to select the answer. No need to vote for it.